# Photons as propellers

Tags: space-travel, light

If I point a torch light backwards in space, why don't I propel forwards because  no matter how small the mass of the particle is , in space you move forward with the same speed you imparted to the particle in the opposite direction. I know photons are massless energy but is this hypothesis possible?

Comment: In point of fact you do, but this question doesn't fit on this site; I'd suggest Physics or perhaps Space Exploration instead.

Comment: Not only is this question a better fit on Physics, but Physics [already has some answers](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112866/if-im-floating-in-space-and-i-turn-on-a-flashlight-will-i-accelerate)

Comment: Atomic rockets does the math, and the result is depressing. You need literally terrawats of energy in the photon beam to produce thrust.

Comment: You don't move in the opposite direction with the same speed as what you fire out the back. The product of velocity times mass is equal. If you fire something that has 1/10 the mass out the back, you move forward with 1/10 the speed that you fired it. (Minus energy lost to friction.)

Comment: I don't think that's applicable in space actually. If an astronaut wanted to go forward with velocity 10 m/s he'd just have to throw a stone backwards wit 10 m/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it in fact does work, but doesn't produce the energy you think it would.

Look at [NASA's ion Propulsion engine.](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/glenn/about/fs21grc.html) It shows out small amounts of electrically charged atoms and it can be used to propel (very slowly) through space. It produces 19-92 milliNewtons worth of thrust.

Edit: 
I misunderstood the question. I thought he meant torch as in a wooden torch.

Even more relevant then are solar sails. They move only by using photons hitting their sails.

> The total force exerted on an 800 by 800 meter solar sail, for example, is about 5 newtons (1.1 lbf) at Earth's distance from the Sun, making it a low-thrust propulsion system, similar to spacecraft propelled by electric engines.

[image]

> Source: [Wikipedia: Solar Sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail)

Comment: If the poster was British, a torch is what Americans know as flashlight.

Comment: @celtschk Thanks for that. I removed the final sentence because I misunderstood the question.